# Setting displays to have separate desktops in Windows 10 similar to “spaces” in Mac OS X

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to find a way to emulate Mac OS X’s "Displays have separate spaces" in Windows 10. I would like separate virtual desktops per display.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new virtual desktop on Windows 10, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. To quickly switch between virtual desktops, use <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can also add virtual desktops by using <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and clicking *New Desktop* in the lower right hand corner.

Comment: This doesn't remotely answer my question

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Is [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18757?locale=en_US) what you're referring to?

Comment: not entirely - specifically this.. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18809 'displays have separate spaces' A Space is not necessarily assigned to a specific screen & changing Spaces doesn't affect all screens, only the one changed. ie, 2 screens, 2 independent Space possibilities on either.